# fix gnuplot installation

Tags: gnuplot, osx-mavericks, homebrew

My gnuplot installation fails because libjpeg cannot not be loaded.

```
$ gnuplot
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gnuplot
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I work with osx-mavericks + XCode 5.1. Gnuplot was first installed in the past under osx-mountain-lion with **homebrew**. And under mountain-lion it worked. I tried to reinstall it now under mavericks, but it does not help.

```
brew reinstall gnuplot --tests
==> Reinstalling gnuplot with --tests
..
==> make
==> make check
  Reason: image not found
/bin/sh: line 1: 30700 Trace/BPT trap: 5       PATH=$bdir/../src:$PATH GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR=$bdir/../src GNUPLOT_LIB=. gnuplot all.dem < /dev/null
make[2]: *** [check-noninteractive] Error 133
make[1]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

Additional info: `brew install libjpeg` says "jpeg-8d already installed" but I can't find libjpeg. I only find several versions of libpng.

```
$ brew install libjpeg
Warning: jpeg-8d already installed
```

P.S. I am not firm with the console. So I am thankful for even simple console tips that help me debug the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ brew reinstall jpeg
```

solved the problem for me. After this I could reinstall gnuplot with

```
brew reinstall gnuplot --cairo --with-x --tests
```

I assume other reinstall options will work too.
Seems like bug in the brew recipe for gunplot. 
At least I expect a better error message.